# Drop down list using javascript in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

Below is my jsp code which shows a dynamic drop down list whenever the page is loaded without any issues,

```
    <td class="label">Order Number<select type="text" style="width:172px" name="branch" >                               
    <option selected value="0">Please select an order</option> 
    <%    
    try
    {   
        Connection conn= DBConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT order as ORDER_NUMBER FROM db2inst1.Orders WITH UR");  
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            %>
            <option value="<%=rs.getInt("ORDER_NUMBER")%>"><%=rs.getString("ORDER_NUMBER")%></option>
            <%
        }                                
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {                             
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }                                
    %>                                                              
    </select></td>
```

I want to know how to avoid the java code in the jsp and get the drop down list via javascript when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad question to answer. I am answering assuming you are absolute beginner.

As a beginner, you can start from servlet. You have to move your java code out from jsp. Though servlet help you to some extent, it has its own limitations.
MVC is the next thing that you have to learn. MVC tries to separate business logic from view. There are a lot of MVC frameworks you can chose from. Struts, struts2, Spring, Wicket are some of them.

Learn JavaScript, jquery which is a popular JavaScript library.

**Also note that stack Overflow doesn't enjoy this kind of question. We expect question with specific problem and you should show your work and issue that you have if any.**